# has_many :through association in the Rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, self, self-reference

I don't get something in the last chapter of the Rails tutorial.

So the aim of this chapter to make friendships with other users, and that makes it a self referential association. (users have a relationship with other users)

So with the User model, there is the Friendship model, that acts as a through table.

And in the code, **class User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :active_relationships,  class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships,  source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
  .
  .
  .
end
```

But I don't get this part:

```
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships,  source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
```

We have to specify in the has_many :through association the table that we are going through (Relationship table). But in the above code there isn't an 
:active_relationships or :passive_relationships table ,there's only a **Relationship** class.

**The Relationship table:**

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

So, my question is, how does that work?

Tnx Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right you have just **Relationship** class.

In rails by default there will be `has_namy :relationships` then you don't have to specify the `class name`.

If you don't follow the **rails default rules**, then when you will try to with **different association name** , you have to specify the **class name**.

In your example

```
has_many :active_relationships,  class_name:  "Relationship",
                               foreign_key: "follower_id",
                               dependent:   :destroy
```

Here you specified to find active relationships from **Relationship** class.

The has_many :through refers to an association.

```
has_many :following, through: :active_relationships,  source: :followed
```

Answer (score 1):

The has_many :through refers to an association, not a table.  The :source is a relationship in the class that that association refers to.

In this case

```
has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
```

refers to this relationship

```
has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                               foreign_key: "followed_id",
                               dependent:   :destroy
```

And in the relationship class, there is a `:follower` that is the actual source for this object.

Comment: Swards, I know that it refers to the name of the association and not the table (class), but I didn't know how rails finds that desired table when the association isn't specified....but I get it now, tnx :)

Comment: Swards, so the association would work even if it were written like this "has_many :followers, through: :relationship, source: :follower"

Comment: I don't think so - there is no `has_many :relationship` on user.  It must be an explicitly mentioned association.